# gen_server: what is `Mon` in `start_monitor/4`?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

The OTP docs say the signature for `gen_server:start_monitor/4` is:

```erl
start_monitor(ServerName, Module, Args, Options) -> Result
OTP 23.0
Types
ServerName = {local,Name} | {global,GlobalName}
  | {via,Module,ViaName}
 Name = atom()
 GlobalName = ViaName = term()
Module = atom()
Args = term()
Options = [Option]
 Option = {debug,Dbgs} | {timeout,Time} | {hibernate_after,HibernateAfterTimeout} | {spawn_opt,SOpts}
  Dbgs = [Dbg]
   Dbg = trace | log | statistics | {log_to_file,FileName} | {install,{Func,FuncState}}
  SOpts = [term()]
Result = {ok,{Pid,Mon}} | ignore | {error,Error}
 Pid = pid()
 Error = {already_started,Pid} | term()
```

What is `Mon`? The docs just say:

> "Mon is a reference to the monitor set up to monitor the server"

So now I know `Mon` is a monitor and that it monitors, but what is its type?

Reading `erlang.erl`, I found:

```erl
-type registered_name() :: atom().
-type registered_process_identifier() :: registered_name() | {registered_name(), node()}.
-type monitor_process_identifier() :: pid() | registered_process_identifier().
```

So is the type of `Mon` `pid() | atom() | {atom(), node()}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mon` is the reference of the monitor:

```erlang
monitor_return({{ok, Pid}, Mon}) when is_pid(Pid), is_reference(Mon) ->
    %% Successful start_monitor()...
    {ok, {Pid, Mon}};
```

(code is [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/e1e43b32408134ffbc6ac616bef2e0fdd1af168c/lib/stdlib/src/gen.erl#L148-L150))

Comment: Thanks! So `Mon` is a `reference()`?

Comment: @MaxHeiber Yes, it's a `reference()`